# Flutter SVG rendering - how to paint image

Tags: flutter, svg

I am testing the use of [undraw library](https://undraw.co/illustrations) assets in my flutter app.

I am using the `flutter_svg` plugin and I am able to display the file properly using the following code

```
final Widget svg = SvgPicture.asset('assets/image.svg');
```

Now I would like to paint the SVG and I see there is a `color` and `colorBlenMode` property.

The problem is that if I set the color then my whole image gets painted. I actually would like to paint only a layer as per the image below.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know if it is at all possible? How could I do it?

Comment: You can use two different images and use `Stack` to show it on another image.

Comment: well ok but I actually would like to paint the image, not stack images. I can color the full SVG file but I would like to know if there is a way to paint only a layer of the SVG using the plugin or flutter

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can solve it doing a SVG by yourself on  [Method Draw](https://editor.method.ac/),  you can draw and paint each component as you want, after that you can convert your SVG code to a Flutter Custom Painter which is basically a draw in flutter, [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/).